# Overriding Subscript operator creates its own variables?

Tags: matrix, subscript

I tried to override the `Subscript` operator to make matrix indexing a bit more "user-friendly" in complex expressions with the following code according to the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html):

```
Subscript[x__] := Part[x]; (* Indexed instead of Part has the same effect *)
```

I defined matrix X<sup>3×2</sup> as `X = Range[10, 15]~Partition~2;`.

Now, I assign this matrix as the first element of an `a` list and I prepend a full-one-row to it. I execute these two commands four times:

```
a = {X};
PrependTo[Subscript[a, 1], ConstantArray[1, 2]];
```

After 4 executions of this cell I get the following dimensions:

```
Dimensions[Subscript[a, 1]] (* {7, 2} *)
Dimensions[Part[a, 1]]      (* {3, 2} *)
```

When I print out the matrices I get two distinct ones:

```
Part[a, 1]
(* {{10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}} *)

Subscript[a, 1]
(* {{1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}} *)
```

I reset `a` to `{X}` on every iteration, despite of this I see `{1, 1}` prepended four times into the a<sub>1</sub> matrix. My question is why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion is arising probably due to a misunderstanding of what `PrependTo` does.  Note that `PrependTo` has attribute `HoldFirst`.  After prepending `ConstantArray[1,2]` to the first part of `a`, the result is stored not in `a`, but rather as a `DownValue` to `Subscript`.  The `Subscript` doesn't get turned into `Part` thanks to the `HoldFirst` attribute.  Also, the symbol `a` never even changes with each call of `PrependTo`, and therefore the code `a={X}` is superfluous.

Starting from a fresh kernel, after running this,

```
Subscript[x__] := Part[x];
```

The following gives the definition associated with `Subscript`:

```
Definition[Subscript]
```

> ```
> Attributes[Subscript] = {NHoldRest}
> Subscript[x__] := Part[x]
> ```

Now set `a={x}` and run your `PrependTo` code once:

```
PrependTo[Subscript[a, 1], ConstantArray[1, 2]];
```

But run `Definition[Subscript]` again, and you'll notice that the following has been added:

> ```
> Subscript[{{{10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}}}, 1] = {{1, 1}, {10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}}
> ```

Therefore, at the very end, when you call `Subscript[a,1]`,  the definition `Subscript[x__] := Part[x];` is not being invoked.  Rather the newly created definition is being called.

Comment: Thank you! As I see, `PrependTo` really has the `HoldFirst` attribute in contrast with the simple `Prepend`, according to `Definition`. However, when I change my code to use `Prepend` the definition of `Subscript` changes again the same way (which I don't understand).

Comment: @szotsaki `Prepend` shouldn't change any definitions (I just checked to confirm).  Be sure to clear the old definitions before checking.  Try again starting from a fresh kernel.

Comment: I ran the code above (fully concatenated is [here](http://paste.opensuse.org/view/simple/7940688)) with a totally fresh kernel and I had two definitions for `Subscript`.
I think this is because `Set` (`=`) has `HoldFirst` attribute (and that can explain why also `PrependTo` has) which causes again a₁ to have an additional definition.

Comment: @szotsaki Ah, I see.  When you said "...to use `Prepend`..." I didn't realize you also mean to use `Set`.  And you're right; it's behaving the same way because of the `HoldFirst` attribute.